# Bash: in directory `directory_name.git`, how to cd to `../directory_name`?

Tags: bash, text-manipulation

I'm pretty new to Bash scripting and am looking to do the following:

The script's pwd is "/a/b/c/directory_name.git/" and I'd like to cd to "../directory_name" where directory_name could be anything. Is there any easy way to do this?

I'm guessing I'd have to put the result of `pwd` in a variable and erase the last 4 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tmpd=${PWD##*/}
cd ../${tmpd%.*}
```

**or perhaps more simply**

```
cd ${PWD%.*}
```

#### Test

```
$ myPWD="/a/b/c/directory_name.git"
$ tmpd=${myPWD##*/}
$ echo "cd ../${tmpd%.*}"
cd ../directory_name
```

*Note: $PWD does not include a trailing slash so the `${param##word}` expansion will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
cd `pwd | sed -e s/\.git$//`
```

The backticks execute the command inside, and use the output of *that* command as a command line argument to `cd`.

To debug pipelines like this, it's useful to use `echo`:

```
echo `pwd | sed -e s/\.git$//`
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
cd "${PWD%.*}"
```

Answer (score 0):

That's what [`basename`](http://Pubs.OpenGroup.Org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/basename.html) is for:

```
cd ../$(basename "$(pwd)" .git)
```

Comment: `basename $PWD` is equivalent to the native shell syntax `${PWD##*/}` but with the added benefit of not having to call an external command

Answer (score 0):

Didn't expect to get so many answers so fast so I had time to come up with my own inelegant solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

PWD=`pwd`
LEN=${#PWD}
END_POSITION=LEN-4
WORKING_COPY=${PWD:0:END_POSITION}

echo $WORKING_COPY
cd $WORKING_COPY
```

There's probably one above that's much more elegant :)